# Find chip serial number connected to USB of linux machine

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to read the serial number on FTDI chip on linux machine. I found below program which does that but the program doesn't retain the value of variable ID_SERIAL outside of for loop.

```
for sysdevpath in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev); do
    (
        syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}"
        devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)"
        [[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]] && exit
        eval "$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath)"
        [[ -z "$ID_SERIAL" ]] && exit
        echo "$devname - $ID_SERIAL"        
    )
done
```

I am trying to avoid any loop to find out serial number on FTDI chips so that the script won't be stuck in the loop if the FTDI serial number match is found.
Or if there is no better way then I want to keep the value of ID_SERIAL outside this for loop and run the for loop again to find other devices.

Comment: perhaps you need to review bash scripting basics ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488651/how-to-break-out-of-a-loop-in-bash

Comment: I can't do that. Since if the number is matched then I want to run a different script and at the same time find another FTDI  chip.

Comment: then focus your question to the actual problem ... it is not `how to read the serial number on FTDI?` ... that part is almost irrelevant ... your problem seems to be `how to start a bash script from within another bash script?`

Comment: I am able to ```run one bash script from another bash script```. I need to run a specific bash script to specific device to get the data I want from that device.

Answer (score 1):

I use this one-liner. Suppose we have a FT2232H which has USB vendor ID of 0x0403 and USB product ID of 0x6010, then you get the serial numbers of all connected FT2232H's like that:

```bsh
$ lsusb -v -d 0403:6010 2>/dev/null | grep iSerial | awk '{ print $3 }' 
FTENC
FTWUU8N5
```